# selfメンバー変数がvarsで取得できないのはなぜでしょうか？

Tags: python, python3

以下のソースコードで、クラスの先頭で宣言した変数がvarsによって取得できません。
`__init__`, `__str__` メソッドにおいて、vars(self)で得られる変数は、`__init__` で宣言した変数 a0, a1, ... のみです。
デバッガにで、ブレイクポイントで停止し、selfメンバーをウォッチすると、先頭で宣言した、b0,b1,....が存在することが分かりました。
クラスのインスタンスからメンバー変数b1を出力すると、正常に出力しています。

これはなぜでしょうか？
`__str__` で self.b0, self.b1 ... をvarsで抜き出したいのですが、できないのでしょうか？

```py
import json

class A():
    for i in range(32):
        exec(f"b{i} = {i}")

    def __init__(self):
        for i in range(32):
            exec(f"self.a{i} = {i}")
        print("__init__",vars(self)) #　ここでブレイクポイントを設定

    def __str__(self):
        vs = vars(self)
        return json.dumps(vs) #　ここでブレイクポイントを設定


a = A()
print(a)
print(a.b1)
```

出力結果

```
__init__ {'a0': 0, 'a1': 1, 'a2': 2, 'a3': 3, 'a4': 4, 'a5': 5, 'a6': 6, 'a7': 7, 'a8': 8, 'a9': 9, 'a10': 10, 'a11': 11, 'a12': 12, 'a13': 13, 'a14': 14, 'a15': 15, 'a16': 16, 'a17': 17, 'a18': 18, 'a19': 19, 'a20': 20, 'a21': 21, 'a22': 22, 'a23': 23, 'a24': 24, 'a25': 25, 'a26': 26, 'a27': 27, 'a28': 28, 'a29': 29, 'a30': 30, 'a31': 31}
{"a0": 0, "a1": 1, "a2": 2, "a3": 3, "a4": 4, "a5": 5, "a6": 6, "a7": 7, "a8": 8, "a9": 9, "a10": 10, "a11": 11, "a12": 12, "a13": 13, "a14": 14, "a15": 15, "a16": 16, "a17": 17, "a18": 18, "a19": 19, "a20": 20, "a21": 21, "a22": 22, "a23": 23, "a24": 24, "a25": 25, "a26": 26, "a27": 27, "a28": 28, "a29": 29, "a30": 30, "a31": 31}
1
```

Comment: 用語的には取得出来ないのは`selfメンバー変数`(インスタンス変数`aX`)ではなく`クラス変数`(`bX`)なのでは？

Comment: `vs = {k: v for k, v in self.__class__.__dict__.items() if k.startswith('b')}`

Comment: こちらの記事も参考に。[Get user-defined class attributes from class instance \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41020233/9014308), [How to get all user defined attributes in types.SimpleNamespace type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27532080/9014308)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

コメントの通り、class宣言の下で直接定義された変数は[クラス変数](https://aiacademy.jp/media/?p=922)として扱われます。
そのため、`b0`...変数は`vars(A)`で取得することができます。

```
import json

class A():
    c1 = "クラス変数" 
    for i in range(3):
        exec(f"b{i} = {i}")

    def __init__(self):
        self.i1 = "インスタンス変数" 

    def __str__(self):
        bs = {x:vars(A)[x] for x in vars(A) if x.startswith("b")}
        return json.dumps(bs)

a = A()
print(vars(a)) # {'i1': 'インスタンス変数'}
print(vars(A)) # {'__module__': '__main__', 'c1': 'クラス変数', 'i': 2, 'b0': 0, 'b1': 1, 'b2': 2, '__init__': <function A.__init__ at 0x...
print(a)       # {"b0": 0, "b1": 1, "b2": 2}
print(a.b1)    # 1
print(A.c1)    # クラス変数
```